# Bootstrap Carousel: disable indicators

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

How to make carousel-indicators not clickable on mobile? So that when I click on them on mobile devices, slides don't change.

I am using latest bootstrap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's change the appearance of the [standard example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-examples) for small screens.

---

### 1. Indicators can be hidden

Add class `hidden-xs` to `<ol class="carousel-indicators">`.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators hidden-xs">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x200/c69/?text=%20" alt="Slide 1">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x200/69c/?text=%20" alt="Slide 2">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x200/9c6/?text=%20" alt="Slide 3">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next"> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
  
<div class="alert alert-danger hidden-xs text-center">
  Width > 767px. Make the window narrower.
</div>
<div class="alert visible-xs text-center">
  Width < 768px. Indicators are hidden.
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

### 2. Indicators can be turned off

Add this CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .carousel-indicators,
  .carousel-indicators li {
    cursor: default;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .carousel-indicators,
  .carousel-indicators li {
    cursor: default;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x200/c69/?text=%20" alt="Slide 1">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x200/69c/?text=%20" alt="Slide 2">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x200/9c6/?text=%20" alt="Slide 3">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next"> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
  
<div class="alert alert-danger hidden-xs text-center">
  Width > 767px. Make the window narrower.
</div>
<div class="alert visible-xs text-center">
  Width < 768px. Indicators are turned off.
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

### 3. Indicators can be placed below the carousel

Add this CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .carousel {
    margin-bottom: 7%;
  }   
  .carousel-indicators {
    bottom: auto;
    top: 105%;
  }
  .carousel-indicators li {
    border-color: #666;
  }
  .carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: #666;
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .carousel {
    margin-bottom: 7%;
  }   
  .carousel-indicators {
    bottom: auto;
    top: 105%;
  }
  .carousel-indicators li {
    border-color: #666;
  }
  .carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: #666;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x200/c69/?text=%20" alt="Slide 1">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x200/69c/?text=%20" alt="Slide 2">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x200/9c6/?text=%20" alt="Slide 3">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next"> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
  
<div class="alert alert-danger hidden-xs text-center">
  Width > 767px. Make the window narrower.
</div>
<div class="alert visible-xs text-center">
  Width < 768px. Indicators are placed below the carousel.
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Option number 2 is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile devices register `touch` events.

So, in your click handler, you can distinguish between `mouse` and `touch` events.

If it is a `touch` event, don't do anything.