# Disabled click in bootstrap carousel-indicators itens

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to disable clicks on carousel-Indicators items, they serve as somenta view.

[image: Image carousel]

```html
<ol class="carousel-indicators indicatorsNumber">
  <li data-target="#carouselCont" data-slide-to="0" class="myCarousel-target btn-default active">1</li>
  <li data-target="#carouselCont" data-slide-to="1" class="myCarousel-target btn-default">2</li>
  <li data-target="#carouselCont" data-slide-to="2" class="myCarousel-target btn-default">3</li>
  <li data-target="#carouselCont" data-slide-to="3" class="myCarousel-target btn-default">4</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Have you tried it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37453050/bootstrap-carousel-disable-indicators

Comment: I do not want to hide the indicators, I want to disable the clicks, they will still serve for visual reference.

Comment: In the same answer there is an item "2. Indicators can be turned off". Check it out...

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `data-slide-to` this will not allow the user to click them, they will serve as an indicator only.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/qh690mk8/